# Fatal error when trying to set up fftw3 with c, MacOS Monterey

Tags: c, makefile, header, fftw

When trying to compile my c code I keep getting `basic.c:5:10: fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found`.  I am compiling my c code using MacOS terminal and have Xcode installed.

I'm trying to write some c code which uses the fftw-3 library.  fftw-3 has been installed using `sudo port install fftw-3` and I have entered `port contents fftw-3` which returned:

```
/opt/local/include/dfftw.h
  /opt/local/include/dfftw_threads.h
  /opt/local/include/drfftw.h
  /opt/local/include/drfftw_threads.h
  /opt/local/include/fftw_f77.i
  /opt/local/lib/libdfftw.2.dylib
  /opt/local/lib/libdfftw.a
  /opt/local/lib/libdfftw.dylib
  /opt/local/lib/libdfftw_threads.2.dylib
  /opt/local/lib/libdfftw_threads.a
  /opt/local/lib/libdfftw_threads.dylib
  /opt/local/lib/libdrfftw.2.dylib
  /opt/local/lib/libdrfftw.a
  /opt/local/lib/libdrfftw.dylib
  /opt/local/lib/libdrfftw_threads.2.dylib
  /opt/local/lib/libdrfftw_threads.a
  /opt/local/lib/libdrfftw_threads.dylib
  /opt/local/share/info/fftw.info
  /opt/local/share/info/fftw.info-1
  /opt/local/share/info/fftw.info-2
  /opt/local/share/info/fftw.info-3
  /opt/local/share/info/fftw.info-4
  /opt/local/share/info/fftw.info-5
```

I have been using a makefile and am trying to work out what needs including in it.  At the moment I have:

```
# define the name of your source file(s)
SRCS = basic.c

# define the name of the object files(s) - we can do this automatically
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# tell MAKE which compiler to use
CCOMP = gcc

# flags for the compiler
# don't forget the -O3
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -Iinclude
#CFLAGS = -c -Wall -Iinclude

# flags for the linker. note -lm for the math library
LDFLAGS = -O3 -lm -L/opt/lib -I/opt/lib -L/opt/local/include -I/opt/lib

# the name of your executable file (the target) - here we put it in the top directory
TARGET = basic

# actions
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CCOMP) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CCOMP) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

# delete all objects and target
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

I'm not sure if the #CFLAGS and #LDFLAGS sections are correct? I would appreciate troubleshooting and any advice on what I need to do to get this working.  Thanks!

Comment: Your `-I` (Include path) needs to go in `CFLAGS` (C compiler options), not `LDFLAGS` (linker options).

Comment: Thanks @PaulR I've given that a go but am still getting the error `basic.c:5:10: fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found`. Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to include a file named `fftw3.h`.  According to the list of files you've provided, there is no file `fftw3.h`.  No amount of compiler flag manipulation will allow you to include a file that doesn't exist.  So, either you are including the wrong filename, or you have not installed the correct package.  Or, the `fftw3.h` file is somewhere else than where you've shown us.  I don't do MacOS so I can't help you find it.

Comment: @MajorFighter: just to make sure we're on the same page, your makefile CFLAGS line should look something like this: `CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -Iinclude -I/opt/local/include`, i.e. there should be a `-I` for the actual path to your fftw3.h header in order for the compiler to find it.

Comment: Correct. `-I/...` for every header file, that is needed in during compilation.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!  I have played around with it and have reinstalled fftw3 and managed to get a package named `/opt/local/include/fftw3.h`.  I have also made sure that CFLAGS looks like `CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -Iinclude -I/opt/local/include`  as @PaulR kindly suggested.  However I am still getting `fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found`.  In my c file I have included fftw3 like `#include <fftw3.h>`.  Any ideas what needs changing to get this to work?  Thanks very much

Comment: You might want to try `#include “fftw3.h”` (double quotes for non-system include files).